# React router is appending style sheets on route changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an application where I have different routes and each route has a component with its own scss file imported to it. The issue is that when I change routes with the  tag the scss styles just get appended to the styles in the header which then cause styling issues on the page because some names are similar. How can i make it so the stylesheets don't get appended every time the route changes?

[image: Every component has its scss file]

[image: This is my style when i first go into the application]

[image: This is the styling after i change to another route]

Comment: Some code could be helpful...

Comment: Do those images help? @JDunken

Comment: Showing here you handle the routing, in both the html and js would be better.

Comment: @JDunken im not following?

Comment: You're showing the effect of the problem, but not the code that causes it. The .js file(s) that invokes the `react-router-dom` package is what I'm talking about, the parts where you define the routes in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap every component with a parent css name.
for example: 
if you have a component named PostList
then your css file would look like this.
post-list.css
.post-list {
    ...css in here
}